# Why am I getting "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column" in LINQ to SQL when I'm not specifying a value for an identity column?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a table that looks like this:
[image]

ClientID is the only identity column I have in the table.  UserID is a FK to a different tables primary key.

Here is my Linq to SQL insert code:

```
public void InsertClientByUsername(string username, Entities.Client clientInfo)
{

    using (LinqModelDataContext db = new LinqModelDataContext())
    {

        var existingClient = (from client in db.Clients
                              join ext_usr in db.User_Extendeds on client.UserID equals ext_usr.FriendlyUserID
                              join asp_usr in db.aspnet_Users on ext_usr.UserID equals asp_usr.UserId
                              where asp_usr.UserName.ToLower().Equals(username)
                              select client).SingleOrDefault();

        if (existingClient != null)
        {
            existingClient.Address1 = clientInfo.Address1;
            existingClient.Address2 = clientInfo.Address2;
            existingClient.City = clientInfo.City;
            existingClient.CompanyName = clientInfo.CompanyName;
            existingClient.CountryID = clientInfo.CountryID;
            existingClient.FaxNumber = clientInfo.Fax;
            existingClient.FirstName = clientInfo.FirstName;
            existingClient.LastName = clientInfo.LastName;
            existingClient.MailingAttention = clientInfo.Attention;
            existingClient.PhoneNumber = clientInfo.PhoneNumber;
            existingClient.StateID = clientInfo.StateID;
            existingClient.ZipCode = clientInfo.Zip;

        }
        else
        {
            int userID = (from ext_usr in db.User_Extendeds
                          join asp_usr in db.aspnet_Users on ext_usr.UserID equals asp_usr.UserId
                          where asp_usr.UserName.ToLower().Equals(username)
                          select ext_usr.FriendlyUserID).SingleOrDefault();

            Client newClient = new Client();
            newClient.UserID = userID;
            newClient.Address1 = clientInfo.Address1;
            newClient.Address2 = clientInfo.Address2;
            newClient.City = clientInfo.City;
            newClient.CompanyName = clientInfo.CompanyName;
            newClient.CountryID = clientInfo.CountryID;
            newClient.FaxNumber = clientInfo.Fax;
            newClient.FirstName = clientInfo.FirstName;
            newClient.LastName = clientInfo.LastName;
            newClient.MailingAttention = clientInfo.Attention;
            newClient.PhoneNumber = clientInfo.PhoneNumber;
            newClient.StateID = clientInfo.StateID;
            newClient.ZipCode = clientInfo.Zip;

            db.Clients.InsertOnSubmit(newClient);

        }

        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

In case you are curious, the reason I have all those assignments is because I'm translating between my POCO domain objects and the linq generated objects.  In the case of this exception, it is taking the path of the else statement, creating a new client.

You can see that I'm *NOT* touching the ClientID property which is the ~only~ identity column in the table.

Why am I getting the "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Client' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF?

In case it is useful, here is my stacktrace:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was
>   unhandled by user code
>   Message="Cannot insert explicit value
>   for identity column in table 'Client'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."
>   Source=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" 
>   ErrorCode=-2146232060   Class=16
>   LineNumber=1   Number=544
>   Procedure=""
>   Server="192.168.168.190"   State=1
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader
>   ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String
>   resetOptionsString)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, String method,
>   DbAsyncResult result)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult
>   result, String methodName, Boolean
>   sendToPipe)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>          at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query, QueryInfo queryInfo,
>   IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   parentArgs, Object[] userArgs,
>   ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object
>   lastResult)
>          at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression
>   query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos,
>   IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[]
>   subQueries)
>          at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query)
>          at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicInsert(TrackedObject
>   item)
>          at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Insert(TrackedObject
>   item)
>          at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode
>   failureMode)
>          at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode
>   failureMode)
>          at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
>          at DomainModel.Repository.Concrete.SqlClientRepository.InsertClientByUsername(String
>   username, Client clientInfo)

Comment: You could use SQL Profiler to look at the generated SQL. But there isnt much doubt that L2S is generating a value. Have a look in the genned code (Project|Show All files) to see whether the metadata for the ClientId column really has the appropriate 'identity marker' (it musnt, or there must be some file version confusion ...)

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink, for some reason it was a weird bug in my generated code.  I deleted my data context and rebuilt it, and this time it worked.  Strange.

Comment: I had the same problem... SqlDesigner issue I guess.

Answer (score 4):

add StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" in the .edmx file (view in txt editor)

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.intrepidstudios.com/blog/2009/2/6/using-default-values-in-linq-to-sql.aspx)

Try setting "Auto Generated Value" to false

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and deleting the table and reading it fixed it.  I don't know about he solution not being pretty, it certainly did the trick and was very quick.  Its ugly in that is a bug in Linq-to-Sql and Visual Studio 2008 (in my case, it could be a bug in other versions too), but its at least a livable bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, but wiping out the entity and importing it back didn't do the trick for me which caused be to have to dig even deeper.  The real issue here is that under the SSDL content of your entity diagram there is a missing attribute (StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity") that should be on the ID property of your entity.  Once you add this attribute you should be all set.

Example:

```
<EntityType Name="TABLENAME">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
  </Key>
  <Property Name="ID" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
</EntityType>
```

Comment: It's also available in the visual editor of the edmx, if you select the column and view it's properties (in VS 2012, at least).

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the table from *.dbml in visual studio and inserted it again. the above problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Read Only` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Martin says, I've had the same problem though I didn't have to delete the whole diagram to fix it. All I had to do was force the diagram to regenerate the code. This is usually just a matter of changing something on the diagram and changing it back. In more severe cases, I've had to restart VS or even reboot to get the designer to regenerate the code.